# Not able to clone repo

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

By default my gitlab repo has both `http` and `ssh`. I was trying to create standalone `terraform` module, and got an error, seems GitLab Runner can't clone the repo.

Here is my `tf module`

```
module     "vpc"   {
   source = "git::https://gitlab.com/space/project/vpc.git"
   ...
}
```

Error

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ terraform init
Initializing modules...

Downloading git::https://gitlab.com/space/project/vpc.git for vpc...
Error: Failed to download module
Could not download module "vpc" (main.tf:10) source code from
"git::https://gitlab.com/space/project/vpc.git":

error downloading
'https://gitlab.com/space/project/vpc.git':
/usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/vpc'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or
address
```

I've tried to clone repo in `ci` however no success

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/space/project/vpc.git
```

Error:

```
Cloning into 'vpc'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 128
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [publish your module](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/terraform_module_registry/#publish-a-terraform-module) to the terraform module registry and also provide authentication information.

You can then specify your source according the published location:

```
source = "gitlab.com/<namespace>/<module-name>/<module-system>"
```

In your `~/.terraformrc` file, you also need to configure credentials to retrieve this module. For example:

```
credentials "gitlab.com" {
  token = "<TOKEN>"
}
```

In a GitLab CI job, you would want to (1) specify `TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE` as a location in the workspace and (2) Create this file as a script step, adding the credentials. You can also use the builtin `CI_JOB_TOKEN` for the `token` credentials.

For example:

```
variables:
  TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.terraformrc
before_script:
  - echo -e "credentials \"$CI_SERVER_HOST\" {\n  token = \"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"\n}" > $TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE
  # - tf ...
```